# Why can I not make the object m1?

Tags: c++, coredump

Im trying to make a new object of the class 'cls' . I have made a no argument constructor which as per my knowledge should have made a new object. But the program crashes with a message Segmentation Fault Core Dumped .

However if I uncomment the line 13 
d = new int;
The program works fine.

//////////////////////////////////////

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class cls
{
    private:
        int *d;
    public:
        cls() {}   //no args ctor
        cls(int a)     //1 arg ctor
        {
            //d = new int;
            *d = a;
        }
};

int main()
{
    cls m{10};
    cls m1;
    cout<<"Testing if program is still fine"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can. The problem is with `m`.

Comment: `cls(int a)` has undefined behaviour, since it dereferences an uninitialised pointer.   This affects initialisation of `m`.  What happens, or not, after that is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*d = a;` will most likely cause a crash since `d` doesn't point to anything valid (it has not been initialized).

Why is `d` even a pointer in the first place? If you just make it a plain `int` you also solve your problem.

Comment: Rather, it has an unspecified value so it causes undefined behavior. Usually it does point to something.

Comment: if I comment out  line 22   //cls m1;  The program runs fine and i can see the text "Testing if program is still fine" in the console.  So I assume *d = a is not the cause of crash.

Comment: @SantoshMainali Don’t assume. Undefined behavior means just that: it’s undefined. It may cause anything, even “it seems to work” when it doesn’t.

Comment: I got the answer. 
I realized 
cls m{10};
cls m1{10}; 
crashes again because the problem had already originated while initializing  m{10} .
Solved.

Comment: @Santosh Mainali - you cannot conclude that. You are storing through a uninitialised pointer. That's Undefined Behaviour and the compiler is allowed to generate *whatever* it wants - it may even *seem to* work some of tthe time.

Comment: @SantoshMainali - you assume incorrectly.   If `d` is uninitialised, then evaluating `*d` (which is part of `*d = a`) has undefined behaviour.    If you initialise `d` appropriately before that, then the behaviour is well defined.     In short:  the line you commented out is what FIXES the problem, in your example.

Comment: Thanking everyone for the insight. All hail stackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

`d` is a pointer, but it is not initialized at  `cls(int a)`,  `d` points to an  unkown address, so sometimes it would not crash, you'd better to code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class cls
{
    private:
        int d;
    public:
        cls() {}   //no args ctor
        cls(int a)     //1 arg ctor
        {
            d = a;
        }
};

int main()
{
    cls m{10};
    cls m1;
    cout<<"Testing if program is still fine"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```